# How do i achieve a page of thumbnails that scroll?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, imageview

I am trying to add a number of images with ImageView in a layout (7 and a text view to be exact) and i wish for two to fit the entire screen side by side at once and then have the ability using scroll view to scroll down and the next two will come up and fill the screen once in position obviously. however ive tried doing this with weights and i cant figure it out for the life of me how would i achieve this effect in xml?

What i currently have that positions the imageViews side by side and scrolls but has large black areas from one imageView to the next below it as the graphic inside the image view doesnt take the entire view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/afflicted_inc"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/afflicted_inc"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/afflicted_inc"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/afflicted_inc"/>



</LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/afflicted_inc"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/afflicted_inc"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/afflicted_inc"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>



        </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: It sounds like you're using a `scrollview` for something that a custom `listview` would work really well for.  There are a number of tutorials out there explaining how to create your own listview (just search for "android custom listview") - for starters check out http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/770/create-custom-listview-in-android/

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones im trying to avoid writing the images in programatically therefore scroll view seemed a more reasonable idea

Comment: So your `scrollview` will always have the same 7 images in it, and this is more just an issue of layout?  What about instead of 1 horizontal `linearlayout` with 2 vertical `linearlayout`s, try 1 vertical `linearlayout` containing 4 horizontal `linearlayout`s, each 2 images across?